# Cypher Query: All actors who have played in the same movie as Hugo Weaving

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to learn Cypher.

[In their online console](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/online_course), I am trying to write a query that will give me all the actors (label "Person") who have played in the same movie as Hugo Weaving.

Based on what I've read so far, this should work:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)-[:ACTED_IN]->(hugo:Person{Name:"Hugo Weaving"})
RETURN p.Name
```

However, it is not.

I've also tried:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE (:Person{Name:"Hugo Weaving"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN p.Name
```

But again - no avail.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(hugo:Person{name:"Hugo Weaving"})
RETURN p.name
```

direction of the relation in your query `(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(hugo:Person` is causing the problem

Comment: check the label, attrib and relationship case. All of them are case sensitive. If possible attach some diagram of your graph

Comment: You were right - I wrote `Name` when it should have been `name`. It works now! Thanks!